# golang: How do I create a new Couchbase pool?

Tags: go, couchbase, pool

Getting into **Go** and **Couchbase**, and for the life of me cannot figure out **how to create a new pool**.

I've checked the code and what docs I could find, but no luck. I'm using the couchbaselabs/go-couchbase library with Couchbase Community Edition 2.2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Pools are more or less a dead feature in Couchbase 2.x, and the go-couchbase api doesn't implement a way to create a new pool.

[What is a couchbase pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978324/what-is-a-couchbase-pool) is relevant.

Comment: Thanks- I've seen that link and it's a good one. My problem may be that my Couchbase install doesn't have a "default" named pool; however, I **can** access /pools/default/buckets (which returns []) using curl.

Comment: post some code on how you connect and the exact error you get, please.

Comment: The actual code is buried in a wrapper library, but it amounts to this: https://gist.github.com/gregkrsak/7e5f8cbcd501006d36ee

Comment: does using `GetBucket` instead of connect / GetPool does anything?

Comment: I don't think that will work; if you notice, in the pools.go of the source, that GetBucket requires a pool name and then takes that name and calls GetPool with it. Ref: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase/blob/master/pools.go

Comment: Indeed, **couchbase.GetBucket("http://127.0.0.1:8091/", "default", "my_bucket")** gives me a *No pool named default* error.