# What is the equivalent of database in Couchbase

Tags: node.js, database, couchbase

There are 3 layers in MongoDB:

1. Server
2. Database
3. Collection

However, in Couchbase I can see something missing; the layers are this way:

1. Cluster (a group of servers)
2. Database (MISSING!!!)
3. Bucket

I need to deploy 2 databases, 1 for development and 1 for production. The missing layer Database puts me on a hard situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can roughly think of a Couchbase bucket as analogous to a database in MongoDB although it seems to be more common in Couchbase to have less buckets and contain multiple types within one bucket (differentiating by using a type field on each JSON object stored).

I'd really recommend not having your development and production buckets on the same cluster, they should be separated at all costs.  Once you run two clusters then you won't have the issue above, you can even run a cluster of vms locally to develop on and then have a real production cluster running on a cloud provider.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a Cluster (all the servers that make up the cluster acting as one)
Then Bucket(s).  Similar to a database.
There are no "Tables" in CB. As what is typically in rows is now in docs.

Where you might have separate databases in SQL, in CB you can put them in one or more buckets.  Buckets are better used as logical, usage, indexing, security, etc. separation.  See this: http://nosqlgeek.blogspot.de/2015/09/how-many-buckets.html

The term pools was introduced in version 1.8 referring to the nodes in a cluster. No longer used in that context.  Latest version is 4.1
You will see the term "pools" in conjunction to groups. Groups are logical grouping of nodes typically used for rack awareness/transaction zone.  So if you have six nodes, with 2 per rack you might have defined Group(pool) 1: Rack1  Group 2: Rack2  Group 3: Rack3  and Couchbase is smart enough to make sure replica docs are not in the same group as the primary doc.

There is also connection pools but I don't think that's what you were referring to...

Answer (score 1):

In the more recent versions of Couchbase, there is now support for scopes & collections. So, it looks like your wish has come true.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/7.0/introduction/whats-new.html#whats-new-server-700

Answer (score 1):

As of Couchbase 7 (currently in beta, GA soon), there are some additional "layers" that might help you.

```
Cluster <-> Server
Database (Catalog) <-> Bucket
Schema <-> Scope
Table <-> Collection
Row <-> Document
```

Those are the rough equivalents, though depending on which database you're comparing Couchbase to, the "left" side of that translation may vary in name.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it out that there is nothing between Cluster layer and Bucket layer in Couchbase.

The only solution I'm using is putting a prefix for all bucket names. eg.

```
databasename.users
databasename.articles
...
```

There is something called 'pool' in Couchbase but possibly feature in future: [What is a couchbase pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978324/what-is-a-couchbase-pool)

```
P.S.
My latest layer mapping for Couchbase:

Server
A cluster, a server, eg. localhost

DB
A bucket, eg. mybucket

Table
A document design, eg. dev_users, and a group of 
documents with doc.type=="user" forms the 'users' table.

Pre-select
A view, eg. dev_users/all_users
```